# AppCode pastes a random string into the editor on pressing Command-Shift-F

Tags: appcode

In AppCode, whenever I press Command-Shift-F it inputs the following string: `6EF0 28B7 43BF 7C04 A7BA 1B17 756E C8C0 9858 E251`.

By default that binds to "Search Everywhere," so it used to just place that string into the search bar. However, if I unbind that shortcut, it will act as if I had typed that string into the editor. I use the IdeaVIM plugin so it does a bunch of random commands and freezes up the editor for a few seconds.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.13.6, AppCode 2018.2.5, and am not using any other accessibility software that might cause this. AppCode is the only program that this behavior happens in.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: We are at least 2 ppl at work who have the same issue. Happens everywhere for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed it!

https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/87979-gpg-keychain-shortcut-key-combination-really-anoying

This turned out to be the solution to my problem.

If that doesn't help you could just uninstall GPG suite by following their guide: https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/kb/faq/uninstall-gpg-suite.